# Proving the Riesz Representation Theorem for $\ell^p$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

> State and prove a Riesz Representation Theorem for the bounded linear functionals on $\ell^p$, for $1 \le p < \infty$.

Let $T : \ell^p \to \Bbb{R}$ be a bounded linear functional, and let $q$ be the conjugate of $p$. Let $e_n$ denote the vector with a $1$ in the $n$-th coordinate and $0$'s elsewhere; and let $b_n = T(e_n)$, which makes since $e_n \in \ell^p$. Then given $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^p$,

\begin{align}
T(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty &= T(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e_n) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n T(e_n) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n, \\
\end{align}

and so it remains to show that $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^q$. To do this, it was suggested, in the chat room, that I look for a sequence $(c_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ for which $T(\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^q$ holds. Well, $c_n = |b_n|^{q-1} sgn(b_n)$ appears to work:

\begin{align}
T(\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne_n) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^{q-1} sgn(b_n) T(e_n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^{q-1} sgn(b_n)b_n \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^q \\
\end{align}

The only trouble is, in order for $T(\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne_n)$ to make sense, it must be the case that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne_n \in \ell^p$ or that $\infty > \sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n|^p = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^q$...It was then suggested that look applying to partial sequence $(b_1,...,b_n,0,...)$, all of which are obviously in $\ell^p$.  I thought that if I could show that $\sum_{n=1}^N c_n e_n \to \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e_n$ in $\ell^p$ as $N \to \infty$, then I would be finished. Sadly, this amounts to showing that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty |b_n|^q \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$; and unfortunately, this does not converge to $0$, unless converges the series itself converges, which I initially and mistakenly thought was true.

I could use a hint on how to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e_n \in \ell^p$.

Comment: Have you tried looking in an introductory functional analysis textbook for the proof that the dual of $\ell^p$ is $\ell^q$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$? That will give you what you need. For example, I'm fairly sure "Linear Functional Analysis" by Rynne and Youngson contains a proof that will solve your problem although I don't have my copy with me right now to check. (although pretty much any such textbook should include this)

Comment: @RhysSteele No, I haven't. The problem comes from Royden's Real Analysis text, which I am working through by myself. As a autodidact, I don't have access to very many resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said all it remains is to show is $\sum_n b_n e_n \in l^q$  i.e $\sum_n c_n e_n \in l^p$.

As you also said $\sum_{n=1}^N c_n e_n \in l^p$ and
$\sum_{n=1}^N |c_n|^p =\sum_{n=1}^N |b_n|^{(q-1)p}= \sum_{n=1}^N |b_n|^{q}$

More over:
$$T\left(\sum_{n=1}^N c_n e_n \right)=\sum_{n=1}^N c_n T\left(e_n \right)=\sum_{n=1}^N c_n b_n=\sum_{n=1}^N |b_n|^{q-1+1}$$

But (and this where you use the continuity of $T$) there exist $C$ ($C=\|T\|_{(l^p)^*}$) such that for all $u \in l^p$:
$$|T(u)| \leq C \|u\|_{l^p}$$
so:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N |b_n|^{q}=\left|T\left(\sum_{n=1}^N c_n e_n \right) \right| \leq C \left( \sum_{n=1}^N |c_n|^p \right)^\frac{1}{p}=C \left(\sum_{n=1}^N |b_n|^{q} \right)^\frac{1}{p}$$
i.e:
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^N |b_n|^{q} \right)^{\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)}=\left(\sum_{n=1}^N |b_n|^{q} \right)^\frac{1}{q} \leq C $$
taking $N \to + \infty$ you obtain:
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^{q} \right)^\frac{1}{q} \leq C$$

Comment: Ah! I was so close! I was playing around with these very inequalities. Thanks for helping me see how to finish the proof!

Comment: What about the case $p = 1$, $q =\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Is the following approach feasible? Picking up from

\begin{align}
T(\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne_n) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^{q-1} sgn(b_n) T(e_n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^{q-1} sgn(b_n)b_n \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|^q \\
\end{align}

we want to show $|| \{b_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1} ||_q \in \ell^q$. By boundedness of T,

$$ \left| \;T( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n e_n) \; \right |  \leq ||T||_{*} \cdot || \{c_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1} ||_p $$

where $||T||_{*}$ is the essential upper bound of T.

By Holder's inequality,

$$ \left|\left| \;T( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n e_n) \; \right| \right|_1  \leq || \{c_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1} ||_p  \cdot || \{b_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1} ||_q$$

Therefore $||T||_{*} = || \{b_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1} ||_q $ and since $||T||_{*} < \infty$, $|| \{b_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1} ||_q$ is also bounded so 
$\{b_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1} \in \ell^q $.

Comment: the assumption is that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_ne_n \in \ell^p$ which is the same issue that OP ran into ...